# Swift error : value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am newbie in Swift, what is this error :

```
let lvt=self?.lastVibrationTime
let delta=self!.deltaTime
let sens=self!.shakeSensitivity
let time:Double = CACurrentMediaTime()

//error is on `lvt` and says : Error:(37, 27) value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
if time - lvt > delta && data.userAcceleration.x < sens {
                    println("firmly shaken!")
                    self?.vibrateMe()
                }
```

Comment: In your if statement, you can try change the `lvt` to `lvt!`

Comment: Guessing "lastVibrationTime" is declared "optional". This means it might be nil, so you need to unwrap it before use.

Comment: @ztan It worked, but what does it mean?

Comment: @gagarwal var lastVibrationTime : Double = 0 // is it optional?

Comment: No, but since you use "self" as optional, which cannot be, so try removing "? and !" after self and you will be just fine.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `let lvt=self?.lastVibrationTime`when using `self?`your lvt variable is optional, you have to unwrap it before using it, you have many solutions to fix this error:

```
1. let lvt = self?.lastVibrationTime ?? 5 // 5 is the default value, you can use the value you want

2. let lvt = self!.lastVibrationTime

3. You can unwrap the value before use it:
if let lvt = self?.lastVibrationTime {
    // your code here...
}
```

Comment: What is difference between `self?.lastVibrationTime` and `self!.lastVibrationTime`

Comment: This is the base of swift language, when using `self?`, you say that you assign the the lvt variable only if `self` is non nil, this is why lvt is optional in your example, when using `self!` you say that you're sure self is non nil, you should use `!`only if you're sure the variable will never be nil.

Answer (score 4):

All your optionals need to be unwrapped. 
So `lvt` should become `lvt!`

**Word of Caution** Unwrapping an optional which doesn't have a value will thrown an exception. So it might be a good idea to make sure your lvt isn't nil.

```
if (lvt != nil)
```

Comment: And why Int can be optional?

Comment: Plenty of reasons. Mostly just because the value could have never been set before. In your case, maybe there was NO last vibration time.

Comment: Everything can be optional. Even optionals can be optional :-)

Answer (score 1):

With this line:

```
let lvt = self?.lastVibrationTime
```

You're acknowledging `self` is optional. So if it's `nil` then `lvt` would be nil; if `self` is not `nil`, then you'll get the last vibration time. Because of this ambiguity, `lvt` is not of type `Double` but an optional, `Double?`.

If you're certain `self` will not be nil, you can force unwrap it:

```
let lvt = self!.lastVibrationTime // lvt is a Double
```

If `self` is nil though, the app will crash here.

To be safe, you can use optional binding to check for the value:

```
if let lvt = self?.lastVibrationTime {
  // do the comparison here
}
```

That means you might need an `else` case here if you have some code to perform in the case of nil.