# Swift issue with example

Tags: swift, enumeration

I'm new to swift and now learning from this book that is called *The Swift Programming Language*. In the book there is an example:

```
enum Rank: Int {
case Ace = 1
case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
case Jack, Queen, King
func simpleDescription() -> String {
    switch self {
    case .Ace:
        return "ace"
    case .Jack:
        return "jack"
    case .Queen:
        return "queen"
    case .King:
        return "king"
    default:
        return String(self.rawValue)
    }
}
}
```

And here is the part I don't understand:

```
if let convertRank = Rank(rawValue: 3){
    let description = convertRank.simpleDescription()
}
```

I tried change the code above to this:

```
let convertRank = Rank(rawValue: 3)
let description = convertRank.simpleDescription()
```

Basically, I have just removed the `if` statement, but then an error occurs: *Value of optional 'Rank?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?*

Why do I have to use an `if` statement? And I don't really understand what does the error message say.

Comment: There are [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799529/value-of-optional-type-string-not-unwrapped) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373958/swift-error-value-of-optional-type-double-not-unwrapped) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662595/value-of-optional-type-cgfloat-not-unwrapped-error-in-swift). Did they not answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if let` is a special `structure` in Swift that allows you to check if an Optional holds a value, and in case it does – do something with the unwrapped value.

In your case:

```
if let convertRank = Rank(rawValue: 3){
    let description = convertRank.simpleDescription()
}
```

The `if let` structure unwraps `Rank(rawValue: 3)` (i.e. checks if there’s a value stored and takes that value) and stores its value in the `convertRank` constant. You can use `convertRank` inside the first branch of the `if`.
Notice that inside the `if` you don’t need to use `?` or `!` anymore.

In your second case:

```
let convertRank = Rank(rawValue: 3)
let description = convertRank.simpleDescription()
```

You can unwrap `convertRank` this way:

```
let description = convertRank!.simpleDescription()
```

> Trying to use `!` to access a non-existent optional value triggers a
>   runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil
>   value before using `!` to force-unwrap its value.

But below code will work same as `if let`:

```
let description = convertRank?.simpleDescription()
```

And program will not crash if `convertRank` is `nil`.

---

More Explanation:

- [What is an optional value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)
- [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Comment: Thank you for the interpretation. This really helps me understand the error, but I have one more question. Do we always use "?" instead of "! "? Is there any advantage to use "!"?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an *Optional* and you have to **unwrap** it before using. You can read about *Optionals* [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

`let description = convertRank?.simpleDescription()` would work.